# Possible determinant relation for PSD matrices.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is $$\det(I+ABC)=\det(I+ACB),$$ when $A,B,C$ are symmetric positive semi/definite and $I$ is the identity matrix. I am mostly interested in the case when the matrices are in complex field.

I know $\det(I+BC)=\det(I+CB),$ when $B,C$ is PSD.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: determinant is invariant under cyclic permutation of elements of the product. I guess that a numerical example will disprove invariance under arbitrary rearrangement. We have $Det(ABC)=Det(CAB)=Det(BCA)$.

Comment: @Maesumi: Actually, the determinant allows any permutation, since $|AB|=|A||B|$. It's the trace that only allows cyclic ones.

Comment: @EricStucky oops! I should have said the characteristic polynomial not the determinant!

Comment: @Maesumi Thank you. So do you think the claim in my question is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $A, B, C$ are real, the statement is true because a real positive semi/definite matrix is symmetric. We have

$$\det(I + ABC) = \det((I+ABC)^t) = \det(I+C^tB^tA^t) = \det(I+CBA) \tag{*1}$$

If $A$ is invertible, we also have
$$\begin{align}\det(I+CBA) = & \det(A)\det(I+CBA)\det(A^{-1})\\ 
= &\det(A(I+CBA)A^{-1}) = \det(I+ACB)\tag{*2}
\end{align}$$

Notice the subset of invertible matrices is dense in the space of matrices and
both $\det(I+CBA)$ and $\det(I+ACB)$ are continuous functions in entries of $A$. 
As a result, $(*2)$ is true even when $A$ is not invertible. Combine $(*1)$ and $(*2)$,
we find
$\det(I+ABC) = \det(I+ACB)$ for real positive semi/definite $A,B,C$.

When $A, B, C$ aren't real, the statement is false. For a counterexample, consider
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}2 &  1\\1 & 2\end{pmatrix},\quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -i\\i & 2\end{pmatrix},\quad
C = \begin{pmatrix}3 &  0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

We have $$\det(I + ABC) = 44+2i \ne 44-2i = \det(I+ACB).$$

Comment: Thank you very much. A small clarification, your $B$ is not symmetric. I assumed symmetric PSD in the question.

Comment: @MLT Achille's $B$ is Hermitian, which is the property that complex PSD matrices have instead of symmetry.

Comment: @VedranŠego Thanks, got it.

Comment: @achillehui You can do without invertibility of $A$ by using [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem): $\det(I+CBA) = \det(I+(CB)A) = \det(I+A(CB)) = \det(I+ACB)$.

Comment: Could you please explain "Notice the subset of invertible matrices is dense in the space of matrices"?

Comment: @MLT Check the [definition of a dense set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set). Descriptively, it means that for every singular $A$ there is some $E$ such that $A+E$ is nonsingular, but also arbitrarily close to $A$. However, you don't need that (see my previous comment).