# Question on dense sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

We have a function $f(x)$, $x \in X$ where $X$ is a complete metric space and say $f()$ is continuous. Then say $f(y)=g(y)$, $y\in Y$, $Y\subset X$, $g()$ is continuous in $Y$, and $Y$ is dense.

(a) Then is $f(x)=g(x)$ in $x \in X$?

(b) If the answer to (a) is yes, will (a) still hold if $Y$ is not dense?

(c) What are the minimum conditions on $Y$ for (a) to hold.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link between a Dense subset and a Continuous mapping](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9532/link-between-a-dense-subset-and-a-continuous-mapping)

Comment: Note that g is not assumed to be continuous on X, only on  Y, I assume, meaning that for the map $g: X$, every point of Y is a point of continuity.

Comment: @studiosus Yes, I take $g$ continious only on $Y$.

Comment: @MLT: Just to confirm, do you mean that $g$ is defined on the entire $X$ but you require every $y\in Y$ be a point of continuity for the map $g: X\to R$? An alternative reading is that $g|Y$ is continuous, which is not the same.

Comment: You need a lot *more* than density. Even if $\overline Y=\overline{Y^c}=X$, there are counterexamples: Let $X=\mathbb R$, $Y=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, $f(x)=0$, $g(\frac nm)=\frac1m$ for $\frac nm\in\mathbb Q$ and $=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @studiosus It is the first of your explanations that I take (not the alternative). Please have a look at the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522825/possible-determinant-relation-for-psd-matrices Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim. Suppose that $X$ i a Hausdorff topological space and $Y\subset X$ is a subset with nonempty complement. Then there exists a pair of function $f, g: X\to {\mathbb R}$ so that

1. $f|Y=g|Y$.
2. $f$ is continuous, $g: X\to {\mathbb R}$ is continuous at every point of $Y$.
3. $f\ne g$ on $X$.

Indeed, pick $p\in X\setminus Y$.  Define functions $f(x)=0, \forall x\in X$, $g(y)=0, \forall y\in Y, g(p)=1$. Then these functions satisfy the claim. Therefore, the asnwer to your question (c) is: If and only if $X=Y$. This also answers questions a and b.